# Setting October 14 ,1582 fails in java.sql.Date

Tags: java, date

If I try to set `java.sql.Date` as
new `java.sql.Date(1582-1900,09,14)`
It returns me

`1582-10-24`

So there is a difference of 10 days. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you give us your code and what exactly you want to achieve!

Comment: I executed System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(1582-1900,09,14))

Comment: The output I am expecting is 1582-10-14

Comment: I ran your code , first shown an error, integer number too large :09, then  `System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(1582-1900,9,14));` it gave an output like : 1582-10-24 .

Comment: The constructor Date(int, int, int) is deprecated.You should not use it

Comment: so can we get 1582-10-14 instead of 1582-10-24? since its showing the wrong date

Comment: Is there any way we can get the correct date from any other constructor?

Comment: @javy:  `09` (like all integer literals starting with zero) would be an octal literal (but 9 is too large for that, you'd need to write `011` to get nine).

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure that date exists?

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) the Gregorian Calender (which is what you are probably using) started on October 15, 1582.

> When the new calendar was put in use, the error accumulated in the 13 centuries since the Council of Nicaea was corrected by a deletion of 10 days. The Julian calendar day Thursday, 4 October 1582 was followed by the first day of the Gregorian calendar, Friday, 15 October 1582 (the cycle of weekdays was not affected).

If you need to deal with days before that, you probably have to write some more involved code.

Comment: so there is no way we can get this date .. since it does not exists?

Comment: Well, it does not exist in the Gregorian calendar. The day itself of course exists. I suppose you would call it "October 4, 1582 in the Julian Calendar". Maybe that is the same as  "October 4, 1582 in the Gregorian Calendar" (but I am no historian or Master Joda). What are you trying to do? Without more context, it is not easy to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the calendar being switched from Julian to Gregorian in that year. (The latter has the 100 and 400 leap year corrections that the Julian calendar lacks. This accounts for the 10 day difference that had accumulated.)

Note that some countries - in particular England - did not adopt that calendar until 1752. And Russia, for example, didn't adopt it until well into the 20th century!

As a rule of thumb, if you're working with dates before 1752 then you ought to consult an historian.